# How to project an element of a nested indexed, non-associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, projection

I have the following document structure (a PHP indexed array without keys):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [country] => Europe
            [year] => 1997
            [id] => 7600522
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [country] => Europe
            [year] => 1997
            [id] => 820426
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [country] => France
            [year] => 1997
            [id] => 12363810
        )
)
```

I am looking for an option to project only `[id]` element of every nested (indexed) array. How do I do this?

I read about `$`, `$elemMatch` and `$slice` operators, but they do not seem to be what I need.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column

Comment: @Sammitch, I don't want to bring unoptimized documents over the network and deal with them as arrays at the server-side. Instead I want to project only those elements that I need at the query level. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research through MongoDB Forums, examining different representations of my data, I noticed that a JSON representation of the PHP array mentioned in my question is semantically different and does not contain indexes like in a PHP array. I used `json_ecnode()` tp convert my indexed PHP array to JSON:

```
[
    {
        "country": "Europe",
        "year": 1997,
        "id": 7600522,
    },
    {
        "country": "Europe",
        "year": 1997,
        "id": 820426,
    },
    {
        "country": "France",
        "year": 1997,
        "id": 12363810,
    }
]
```

Note, that there are no array indexes in JSON like what PHP's `print_r()` displays.

The rest was fairly easy. I ran the query:

```
$options = array(
  'limit' => 3,
  'projection' => array(
    '_id' => 0,
    'id' = >1
  )
);

$cursor = $mongodb->mycollection->find(array(), $options);
```

which brought me the desired dataset.